# Is it possible to retrieve GPS location when dynamic QR code is scanned and sent via text?

Tags: text, dynamic, gps, location, qr-code

**Retrieve GPS Location When Dynamic QR Code is Scanned And Sent Via Text**

I am looking for help with creating a dynamic QR code that when scanned, takes the user to an URL and at the same time sends me the GPS coordinates or location. Is this possible?

I have seen many QR code generators, however, I am looking to see if it is possible to develop the QR code myself, to avoid paying for a service. I have access to some software but was unsure of what software is used to create a QR code generator.

Any insight or ideas would be appreciated. I hope I posted this in the correct area. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

There are at least two ways.

#### Use a single QR code and device GPS location

Generate a QR code which takes the user to `example.com`. Then `example.com` asks the user for permission to access the device's GPS location. The user agrees, the webpage sends the location to the server, and then the server sends you a text with that location.

#### Use a different QR code for every location

Make a unique QR code for each location where you post each of these QR codes. The link contains the coordinates where the QR is placed. So the QR code in LA links to `example.com/34°03′N 118°15′W`, the QR code in New York links to `example.com/40°42′46″N 74°00′22″W`.

Every time a user accesses one of these URLs, the server sends you a text.

#### Edit: What's a QR code?

You mentioned wanting to develop your own software to generate QR codes. That's not the hard part of this. There many sites which will generate QR codes for you for free.

A dynamic QR code is just a static QR code that points to a URL. All that these service which sell "dynamic QR codes" do is host a website which redirects that redirects that static URL (e.g `example.com/123asdf1`) to your true content.

The hard part is writing that website to which the QR code will link.